# How can I lemmatize english words (example: 'run' and 'ran') using R to bring them all to the same tense?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, string-matching, lemmatization

I want to lemmatize english words such that all of them get converted to the same tense. For example:

```
c("ran","run","running")
```

should become `c("run","run","run")`.

I have already explored R packages such as tm, wordnet, RTextTools, and Snowball C; but all of them result in the output `c("ran","run","run")`. As you can see, they do not convert "ran" to "run".

Comment: This answer might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/36234096/2026277

Comment: Thanks Jaime!. Do you think Python provides packages to do this without the need for scraping the web (as used in this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/36234096/2026277). Thanks again :)

Comment: There are some downloadable lemma lists at the bottom of this page that might be worth investigating... http://www.laurenceanthony.net/software/antconc/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [**textstem** package](https://github.com/trinker/textstem#lemmatizing) I maintain:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(textstem)

lemmatize_words(c("ran","run","running"))
###[1] "run" "run" "run"
```

Note that if you actually have strings and not word vectors you may want the `lemmatize_strings` function instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tyler!