# Strange lemmatization result in r, textstem package

Tags: r, lemmatization, lexicon

I would like to get lemma "dive" from all possible forms of the word using textstem package in R.

But when I used textstem package in r, the basic form becomes a very strange result.

```
library(textstem)
words<-c("dived", "diving", "dive")

lemmatize_strings(words, dictionary = lexicon::hash_lemmas)

[1] "dive" "dive" "diva"
```

Here, I do not want "dive" as a result from a word "dive", instead I need to lemmatize the word "dive" into "dive", so it can be counted as the same word with other forms "dived", "diving". So it should be like this, below.

```
[1] "dive" "dive" "dive"
```

I found this link ([stemDocment in tm package not working on past tense word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230641/stemdocment-in-tm-package-not-working-on-past-tense-word/36234096#36234096)), but it might not be useful in my case since I would have to process more than 80,000 reviews and I am highly likely to come across the same problem with different words.

I use `lemmatize_strings`for the dataset I have but it gives exactly the same result (though it's bit obvious). Can anyone please help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Adjust your table? `lemmas <- lexicon::hash_lemmas[token=="dive",lemma:="dive"];lemmatize_strings(words, dictionary = lemmas)`.

Comment: @lukeA, Perfectly worked thus problem solved! Thank you very much!

Comment: Let's make it ' lemmata` though instead of `lemmas` ;)