# Text Analysis and dealing with grammar, tense in R

Tags: r, grammar, text-analysis, word-cloud

I am trying to do text analysis in R. I am able to do the frequency counts and wordcloud. But I could not figure out how to work with the words which are same but different tense such as "enjoy", "enjoyed". I want these words to count as single word "enjoy" rather than 2 separate words. Is there are way I can fix these words or change to present tense?

Comment: I think you will probably have to use a specialized R package to handle this, if one exists.

Comment: Generally this is dealt with by [stemming](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230641/stemdocment-in-tm-package-not-working-on-past-tense-word

Answer (score -1):

You can either use stemming as a pre-processing step or use the Quanteda package and employ a wildcard pattern match by specifying "enjoy*" to include variations such as "enjoyed" and "enjoying"